# Rshiny network graph on server without Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, linux, server, graph-theory

I'm developing an Rshiny app which focusses on finding the shortest routes in a network graph. Unfortunately, the server is too old to support GNU development tools for Rcpp, so packages like igraph do not work, nor would anything using Rcpp like defining my own C++ functions.

One option I am considering is that Rshiny could be used to trigger the C++ script which runs independent of R in the server, and then the results are fed back in to Rshiny. Does anyone know if this is possible?

The two other options I am considering are: b) using a different language within R (like Python or Perl - probably slower than C++, may require other software incompatible with server/Linux version), and c) Pre-compiling the C++ code in an environment with the right compilers, and then transferring it to the old server/Linux .. shucks then this still has to communicate with R. Any suggestions welcome. Obviously getting a new server is a good option.

Best regards,

Sarah

Comment: Hi Sarah. Stackoverflow community is focused in coding problems. There are other platforms where you can ask more general recommendations like this. You'll get better results. Trust me! ;)

Comment: Thanks Francisco. Could you please specify what these sites are where I can ask such a for general recommendations?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Don't know exactly wich one is the appropiate